What does adding/using Application Insights from Visual Studio do?
I have added Application Insights to my app by following the Blazor server instructions here. As listed, I added the NuGet package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.
However, in Visual Studio, if I RMB my web project, it has Add | Application Insights Telemetry and Application Insights | Configure Application Insights. Are these just a different way of accomplishing the same thing? Or is this something different?
And if something different, what are they?

You can find few differences with both the configurations.The first one with Javascript gives you the no. of sessions and page views in the usage section.Will explain in detail.


What does adding/using Application Insights from Visual Studio do?


Adding Application Insights from Visual Studio provides an option to create/select the Application Insights Resource and updates the App with required code (Program.cs code and appsettings.json config).


Dependency configuration progress :
Connecting to Azure Application Insights dependency appInsights1 in the project...
Configuring settings files...
Adding settings to C:\Users\****\source\repos\July\BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2\appsettings.json...
Adding ApplicationInsights/ConnectionString to C:\Users\****\source\repos\July\BlazorApp2\BlazorApp2\appsettings.json...
Configuring project properties...
Adding project property 'ApplicationInsightsResourceId'...
Adding APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING to store LocalSecretsFile...
Installing NuGet packages to project...
Installing package 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore' with version '2.21.0'.
Skipping package 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', same version or a newer version is already installed.
Adding code to Startup.cs...
Serializing new Azure Application Insights dependency metadata to disk...
Generating ARM template...


The Required NuGet Packages are installed automatically.

My .csproj:
<ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/**/resourceGroups/**/providers/microsoft.insights/components/AppInsights</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
<UserSecretsId>**</UserSecretsId>
  -------
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />


Visual Studio does not involve any manual code or configuration for basic Application Insights,but if you need any additional or custom telemetry you need to add the required packages and  code .

Whereas the JavaScript SDK involves manual adding JS script in razor file.

You can see the script has inbuild pageview, events etc..

Using SDK, you can get the Pageviews directly.




If I do the above, I still need to add the calls AddApplicationInsights, AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry, and ConfigureTelemetryModule (SQL enable) - correct? TIA

Yes..you are correct.To track sql queries you need to configure TelemetryModule.AddApplicationInsights will be added in default code as I mentioned above.

Please refer SoThread to track sql queries

Also refer this MsDoc
